# Completeness and isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

> İf the metric spaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ are isometric and $X_1$ is complete, show that $X_2$ is complete.

I just know the definition. Can we conclude from the definition that every Cauchy sequence is convergent?

Answer (score 11):

If you have a Cauchy sequence in $X_2$ you can map it into $X_1$ (which is complete) using your isometry. Isometries preserve the metric, so you know something about the image sequence.

To be more precise: let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X_2$ and $T: X_2 \to X_1$ the isometry. By definition, we have $d_1(Tx_n, Tx_m) = d_2(x_n,x_m)$, and so $Tx_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X_1$ (to see this, write down the definition of a Cauchy sequence). As $X_1$ is complete, the sequence converges to some point $y\in X_1$. Since $T$ is a bijection, there is some $x\in X_2$ which maps to $y$. Now you need to show that the original sequence converges to $x$.

Comment: No really .can you help more in this